# Easiest way to alert users in IE that the page is not supported in IE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer, nuxt.js

I'm looking for the easiest way to tell users on any version of IE that the webpage does not work in IE. A simple alert will do.

**Stack**

Vue 2, Nuxt 2

**Issue**

IE can't interpret ES6, so an alert in mounted or any method for that matter, does not work.

I read somewhere that writing:

```
mounted: function () {}
```

Instead of:

```
mounted() {}
```

Should do the trick, but it does not.

I'd rather not use polyfills just to create this alert, since the whole idea is to finally stop supporting IE.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `alert in mounted` ... no possible way in mounted, no code will be successfully parsed, so, absolutely not possible in there -

Comment: Where then? I can't place script tags in the template. And {{ alert('GTFO') }} won't even work in modern browsers // _vm.alert ni not a function

Comment: best way `<script nomodule>do it in here</script>` in your `index.html` file - this will only run in OLD browsers

Comment: We only have a index.vue file, same thing or nah? @JaromandaX

Comment: oh, `nuxt` - not sure then

Comment: I use this JS in my Angular project, it should work with yours vue too:
`/msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent)` .

Just in case, keep in mind this must be handled differently on SSR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
Placed a js file in the static folder, added it in head in nuxt config.
I make sure its client-side in the script before doing anything.